# Getting multiple table names from a single MYSQLi query

Tags: php, mysqli

How can one get the table names from such a query using PHP and the query is run with MYSQLi

```
Example
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field3, table2.field4 FROM table1,table2
```

Result

```
array(table1,table2)
```

This is the code Im using but it only get the name of the first table

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $numOfFields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfFields; ++$i) {
         $tableinfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, 1);
         var_dump($tableinfo->orgtable);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance Im not so good at PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the hard coded number 1 with the variable $i, like this way:
Try it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfFields; ++$i) {
         $tableinfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
         var_dump($tableinfo->orgtable);
}
```